# reference to another Google sheet by its index in formula

Tags: google-apps-script, indexing, google-sheets, reference, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a generic formula in a google sheet to refer to a cell in the "previous" sheet.
This means I need to be able to reference it without using its name, but rather using its index number.

It would look something like this.

```
=getsheetbyindex(thissheetindex()-1)!A1
```

I'd like to do this without a script. I've searched and tried to look into google's help, but couldn't find a way to access a sheet by anything but its name.

Edit : it's ok to use a script function, what I meant is that I want to do this in the cell formula itself, not in a script.

Comment: possible only with script. you want it by GID number or by index number??

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'd like by index number so that I can "+1" for next or "-1" for previous sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

script:

```
function SHEET(input) {
try {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets() ;
  if( (input>0) && (input <= sheets.length)) return sheets[(input-1)].getName() ;
  else return "invalid sheet #" ;
}
catch( err ) {
  return "#ERROR!" 
}
}
```

formula for first sheet:

```
=SHEET(1)
```

formula for 5th sheet:

```
=SHEET(5)
```

etc.

Comment: if you want it draggable use: `=SHEET(ROW(A1))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's very close to what I'm trying to achieve. With your solution I can get the sheet name from its index. But what I need is being able to set a formula refering to the previous sheet. When I tried to do that, I got the text of the cell correct, but it's not interpreted as a formula. For example, the formula of the cell is ="='"&get_sheet_name(this_sheet_index()-1)&"'!A5" where get_sheet_name is your function. The result is ='Sheet1'!A5 but appears as text and is not interpreted as a formula since it's already the result of the first formula. Hope this is clear enough...

Comment: try to wrap it into INDIRECT

Comment: I tried : =INDIRECT(get_sheet_name(this_sheet_index()-1)&"!A5") and get the #REF error : parameter 1 of INDIRECT is "Sheet1"!A5 which is not a correct cell... But is I type this myself in another cell it works, so it looks pretty correct to me. Any hint ?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Got it to work, I've added quotes in the sheet name function, and it's not required as it's already a string. Thanks a lot player0 !